# Using javascript editor in my eclipse

Tags: java, javascript, eclipse

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. I have installed eclipse in it. I want to write javascript files in eclipse so I installed one javascript plugin (Programming Languages -> javascript development tools) in eclipse. When I write Java programs I get default proposals. Like when i just write System.  I get a list of menu that contains properties of System class. But why this is not happening with Javascript files. When I write document. and press CTRL + SPACE, I get no "No Default Proposal Message". Let me know what I am missing here.I just want the Default Proposals when I write js code in eclipse.

Comment: What version of eclipse are you using?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `Other Javascript Proposals` option in the default content asiist list.

To do that,

1. Go to `Windows` >> `Preferences`
2. Then `Javascript` >> `Editor` >> `Content Assist` >> `Advanced`
3. In the right pane, make sure `Other Javascript Proposals` is **ticked** as shown in the image below:

[image: Preferences Screenshot]